# Testing on different operating systems

Tags: testing, operating-systems

I am a developer who has windows 7 installed as the host operating system with vmware. I have linux installed using vmware. Therefore I am able to test java and c++ apps on windows 7 and Linux.

I also want to test them on windows 8 and I want to familiarise myself with windows 8.

I am debating whether to upgrade my host operating system to windows 8 or install it on vmware?

Comment: I would recommend testing all of it within VMware, both windows 8 and Windows 7 even. Your development environment likely has a great deal of differences between a typical deployment machine, that can easily mask many kinds of bugs and configuration issues.

Comment: @whatsisname I think you should make this an actual answer.

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend testing all of your target operating systems within VMware, both Windows 8 and Windows 7, using a VM for Win7 instead of your development environment.

Your development environment likely has a great deal of differences between a typical deployment machine, that can easily mask many kinds of bugs and configuration issues.

Testing on 'fresh' virtual machines, you can test and verify that you aren't forgetting any dependencies, configurations, etc that you need to run your software.

Comment: Note you can run OSX on VMWare Player too if you know what to do!

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever working environment you feel is most productive for you and test in VM on all target platforms including the operating system you're using.

This approach gives you:-

- a consistent starting point
- a reproducible system (where others can repeat your tests given your VM)
- freedom from dependencies
- separation of dev / test environments

As for if you should use windows 8 or not, that's up to you...  My experience has been that after installation you struggle with the new UI for a few days and then wonder what everyone made all the fuss was about (it's basically just that people fear change when you get to the bottom of it.)  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Use VMs. Snapshotting is extremely useful for testing. Snapshot it, do your test, and blow it away again, always mean you have a clean test environment. Also, you can clone a template, install version A in one, version B in another, and perform your tests against each. Very good to identify/spot regressions. Also, it is easier to adjust the system specification, you can ramp down the memory allocation to simulate a resource constrained environment, for example.

Answer (score -4):

It's better to install Windows 8 in VMWare so that you can test it for the time being, and testing will not create any problems for your system.

Comment: this post does not seem to offer anything substantial over what has been already explained in [prior answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/215719/31260). Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to fit [answer] guidelines