# When I need to confirm that my software works on an OS not installed on my workstation, are there disadvantages to using a virtual environment?

Tags: testing

I want to confirm that my software works on an OS that is not installed on my workstation. So I want to use a virtual environment to test it.

I am worrying there are disadvantages about that.

Are there disadvantages for testing software in a virtual environment?

OS what I mean, operating system.

Comment: What *exact OS* are you thinking of (that "you don't have")? Most software need some specific OS API. The [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard defines some well defined API. And what kind of software are you coding? Some weird (academic) operating systems don't even have files! So **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: You probably should take days to read [Operating System : three easy pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) or find some course on operating systems in Japanese.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing on different operating systems](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215698/testing-on-different-operating-systems)

Comment: I would like more answers. If you can answer to me... *Answer to me*!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Virtual machines are very good. If your software works in a virtual machine, it should also work on a real machine. But sometimes, the software would work on a real machine but fails in a virtual machine:

- if the software needs access to special hardware, like direct access to USB ports, graphic cards, ….
- if the software needs direct network access.
- if the software is related to virtualization. You can't create nested virtual machines.

So for most software, virtualization works well. There are a couple of disadvantages to virtual machines in general:

- they use a lot of RAM while they are running. This limits the number of virtual machines you can run at the same time.
- they take some time to boot up and shut down. You can't quickly test something.
- if the virtual machine runs on an *emulator*, the virtual machine will be much slower. This is necessary if the OS runs on a different CPU architecture. For example, you are developing on a x64 machine, but want to test on ARM (mobile phones) or Sparc (Sun/Oracle servers).

I have used a lot of virtual machines for testing, and it was much easier than running many physical machines.

Comment: A VM only provides a virtual hardware execution environment. It still requires you to run the particular OS you want to test on. But the OP said he doesn't *have* that particular OS.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: what the OP wrote literally and what he actually meant are probably two different things.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand that as “I don't have that OS installed on a physical machine/don't want to dual-boot/don't have separate hardware” not “I don't have access to the OS”. Then, a virtual machine can help. If the problem actually is “I want to develop for Mac OS/iOS/AIX mainframes/Arduino/Windows but don't want to buy the necessary hardware/software” then no amount of virtual machines will help.

Comment: @amon: stay calm, I edited the question to make it more clearer.